# How to validate gmail access token on server side

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller, c#-4.0, google-oauth

I want to validate gmail access token on sever 
   (ie. in action of a controller).
    I am able to get access token by below code:

```
now I want to validate this access_token (received by onSignIn  
function) by c# code on sever side.
I am sending email id & access_token to the sever by ajax call. 
i have no idea what to do next , please help me. Thanks in advance

function onSignIn(googleUser) {
        var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();  
        idToken = googleUser.Zi.access_token
        id = profile.getId();
        console.log('ID: ' + profile.getId()); 
        console.log('Name: ' + profile.getName());
        console.log('Image URL: ' + profile.getImageUrl());
        console.log('Email: ' + profile.getEmail()); 
        ValidateAccessToken(id, idToken);
    }
```

Comment: You should read this [article](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth) on Authenticating a Google Sign-In on the backend

Comment: @user1538301  I have read it. i want validate token in c# code on server side and i dint find any solution for that. thanks for response

Comment: Well, there's a lot of ways you can do it. You need to know how to make an API/HTTP call in C# and how to deal with its response in a manner that is synchronous (at least for the context of the request) so that you can make an API call in your Controller Action and generate a response from Google's response.

Just start by looking up how to make an API/HTTP call in C# or .NET (here's an [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client) I just found by searching 'how to make an http call in c# .net')